# Redshift Left Join with filter drops Non-matching records

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have this sample query below where I have 3 ids in #txn and one of the ids are not in the #lkp.

When I left join that includes a filter from #lkp to exclude some values of grp, one of the records get dropped. My desired output is to still keep all records in my #txn even if they do not match with any record in the #lkp.

Is this a standard behavior for all SQL (MS SQL, MYSQL, etc.)?

```
drop table if exists #txn;
create table #txn(
  id int,
  var1 int
);

drop table if exists #lkp;
create table #lkp(
  id int,
  grp int
);

insert into #txn values (101,123);
insert into #txn values (102,456);
insert into #txn values (103,789);

insert into #lkp values (101,0);
insert into #lkp values (103,1);

select
  a.id,
  a.var1
from #txn a
left join #lkp b on (a.id = b.id)
where b.grp not in(10,20)
;
```

Comment: Yes this is standard SQL behaviour. You need to move the `WHERE` condition into the `ON` condition i.e. `on (a.id = b.id) AND b.grp not in(10,20)`

Comment: It's because of the WHERE clause. When you left join, 3 records will show up but lkp.grp is blank so record gets dropped from results. You can add OR clause i.e. (b.grp in (10,20) OR b.grp IS NULL)